# Not able to fetch the data from a temporary file that is from Team_Details.txt, i am not able to fetch the data what ever i had given as input

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000

int write()
{
    char team_name[50];
    int i,n;
            printf("------------------------------------------------------");
            printf("\n");
            
            printf("Enter number of Teams: ");
            scanf("%d",&n);
                     FILE *fptr;
                     fptr=(fopen("Team_Detail.txt","a"));
            if(fptr==NULL)
            {
                printf("Error!");
                    exit(1);    // exit(1) (usually) indicates unsucessful termination. However, it's usage is non-portable.
            }
    for (i=0;i<n;++i)
     {      
            printf("------------------------------------------------------");
            printf("\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Enter the Team Name:-");
            scanf("%[^\n]",team_name);
     }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;


}

int display()
{
    FILE * fptr;

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    int totalRead = 0 ;

    fptr = fopen("Team_Detail.txt","r");

    if(fptr == NULL)
    
    {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        printf("Please check whether file exists or no");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    
    }
    printf("------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n");

    while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fptr ) != NULL) 
    {
            totalRead = strlen(buffer);
            buffer[totalRead - 1] = buffer[totalRead - 1] == '\n' 
                                    ? '\0' 
                                    : buffer[totalRead - 1];

            printf("%s\n", buffer);
     printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n"); 
    }

    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
              

}

int main()
{
    printf("------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\nFootball League System\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------");
    int choice, num, i;

     while(1)
    {   
        printf("\n");
        printf(" Press 1 to Enter the Details of the Team \n");
        printf(" Press 2 to Display Team Details \n");
        printf(" Press 3 to Exit \n");
        printf("------------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter your choice :  ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                write();        // Here, Calling "team_attributes()" Function
                break;

            case 2:
                display();
                break;
            
            case 3:
                printf("program finished\n");
                exit(0);
                break;
               
            default:
                printf("Invalid Input entered\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

with the above code I am able give my input and whatever input i give is stored in a temporary text file, but i am unable to display the dat which is present in the temporary text file, Can you guys please help me with this. And also can anyone please suggest me the logic for scheduling matches between the teams by fetching the data of teams temporary text file .

Answer (score 0):

-in your `write()` you are getting input through `scanf()`, but not writing them in txt file.
-use functions like `fputs()` to write the data in txt file.
I'm adding this code to write data in txt file

```
fputs(team_name,fptr);
```

Modified version:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000

int write()
{
    char team_name[50];
    int i,n;
            printf("------------------------------------------------------");
            printf("\n");

            printf("Enter number of Teams: ");
            scanf("%d",&n);
                     FILE *fptr;
                     fptr=(fopen("Team_Detail.txt","a"));
            if(fptr==NULL)
            {
                printf("Error!");
                    exit(1);    // exit(1) (usually) indicates unsucessful termination. However, it's usage is non-portable.
            }
    for (i=0;i<n;++i)
     {
            printf("------------------------------------------------------");
            printf("\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Enter the Team Name:-");
            scanf("%[^\n]",team_name);
            fputs(team_name,fptr);
     }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;


}

int display()
{
    FILE * fptr;

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    int totalRead = 0 ;

    fptr = fopen("Team_Detail.txt","r");

    if(fptr == NULL)

    {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        printf("Please check whether file exists or no");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
    printf("------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n");

    while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fptr ) != NULL)
    {
            totalRead = strlen(buffer);
            buffer[totalRead - 1] = buffer[totalRead - 1] == '\n'
                                    ? '\0'
                                    : buffer[totalRead - 1];

            printf("%s\n", buffer);
     printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;


}

int main()
{
    printf("------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\nFootball League System\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------");
    int choice, num, i;

     while(1)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf(" Press 1 to Enter the Details of the Team \n");
        printf(" Press 2 to Display Team Details \n");
        printf(" Press 3 to Exit \n");
        printf("------------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter your choice :  ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                write();        // Here, Calling "team_attributes()" Function
                break;

            case 2:
                display();
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("program finished\n");
                exit(0);
                break;

            default:
                printf("Invalid Input entered\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```